# Topological manifolds which cannot be embedded into any Euclidean space

Tags: general-topology, manifolds

I take the definition that a (topological) manifold is a topological space which is second-countable, Hausdorff, and locally Euclidean. Munkres proves that every compact manifold can be embedded into some Euclidean space.

What is an example of an (topological) $m$-manifold which cannot be embedded into $\mathbb{R}^n$ for any $n\in\mathbb{N}$? What is the smallest $m\in\mathbb{N}$ for which such an $m$-manifold exists?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There is no such manifold, and in fact invoking dimension theory shows that more is true. In the same book (Munkres' *Topology*), exercise $\S$50.7 (p. 315 in my edition) is to prove the following:

> Every [topological] $m$-manifold can be imbedded in $\Bbb R^{2 m + 1}$.

This result is a corollary of the following theorem, whose proof is in turn the content of the somewhat technical multi-part problem $\S$50.6:

> **Theorem** Let $X$ be a locally compact Hausdorff space with a countable basis, such that every compact subspace of $X$ has topological dimension at most $m$.
>   Then $X$ is homeomorphic to a closed subspace of $\Bbb R^{2m+1}$.

I do not know whether the dimension $2 m + 1$ can be sharpened to $2 m$.

Comment: That theorem only applies to smooth manifolds. My question is about topological manifolds.

Comment: Also, the Whitney Embedding Theorem is not stronger than what Munkres proves since Munkres’ proof applies to compact non-smooth manifolds.

Comment: Oops, I misread the question. The claim is still true if we replace "smooth" with "topological" and if we relax $2 m$ to $2 m + 1$ (I'm not sure whether it's possible to reduce to $2 m$). I'll update my answer.

Comment: For compact spaces we can say $2m$ for smooth manifolds. This is quite non-trivial.

Comment: Thanks, Henno. I found essentially this question on mathoverflow: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/34658/is-there-a-whitney-embedding-theorem-for-non-smooth-manifolds If I understand the case $k = 0$ of Corollary 4.14 of https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0612085.pdf correctly implies that we can achieve $2m$ for all manifolds, at least for $m \geq 4$ (but I would be happy to be disabused). This bound is good for $m = 2$, too, and I'd guess for $m = 3$ but I don't know a proof.